# Principal ultrafilter on a cardinal $\lambda$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, filters

How do I most straightforwardly **prove** that if an ultrafilter on a cardinal $\lambda$ is principal, then it is of the form
all subsets of $\lambda$ containing $\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\lambda$?

What is the most direct reason why such an ultrafilter cannot contain all supersets of a non-singleton set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your definition of principal is $\{F\subset E\mid  A\subset F\}$ for some $A$ ? (it is often in the definition of "principal" that $A=\{x\}$)

In that case, since $\mathcal{U}$ is an *ultra*filter, if $B\subset A$, $B\neq A,\emptyset$, what do you make of the question "does $B\in \mathcal U$ ?"

Comment: For your first assumption the answer is "yes". For your "make" I don't know: either $B$ is in $\cal U$ ot $E\setminus B$ is in $\cal U$. What reasoning is next?

Comment: If $B\in \mathcal{U}$, what does that imply with regards to $A$ ? If $E\setminus B\in \mathcal U$, what do you think of $(E\setminus B)\cap A$ ?

Comment: If $E\setminus B\in\cal U$ then also $E\setminus B\cap A\in\cal U$. And if $B\in\cal U$ then $B$ has fewer elements then $A$. How to finish?

Comment: They are *proper* subsets of $A$ and they contain $A$, isn't that a bit odd ?

Comment: Why is $(E\setminus B)\cap A$ a *proper* subset of $A$ ? I'm sorry I'm high school student. GOT IT!

Comment: Because I chose $B\neq \emptyset$ (no worries, I would have given more explanations had I known that - good luck on your learning this more advanced stuff !)